# LINQ to custom class when grouped by identifier

Tags: c#, linq, class, datatable, datatables

I have a data table in which I need parsed into a manageable set of class data. This is not a difficult task in most cases, however, I am needing to group items together in these custom classes to make sense out of them.

### Classes

```
public Parent
{
    Parent(){ }
    public int ParentID = 0;
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public List<Children> Child = new List<Children>();
}

public Children
{
    public Children() { }
    public string ChildID = 0;
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public List<string> ChildBooks = new List<string>();
}
```

### Table

```
 Parent ID |     Parent      | Child ID |     Child     |     Books 
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | Grapes of...
1          | John            | 4        | Suzy          | Huck........
1          | John            | 5        | James         | The adven...
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | Grapes of...
2          | Sally           | 4        | Suzy          | Huck........
2          | Sally           | 5        | James         | The adven...
```

### Result

```
List<Parent> First index would be
Name: John
Child: 4 Suzy, 5 James

Second index would be
Name: Sally
Child: 4 Suzy (Grapes of..., Huck.....) 5 James (The adven...)
```

Is there a less messy way of achieving this? My current method involves grabbing each `Distinct` ParentID, linking them back to children and creating the class there. I haven't yet written this portion of the code, but if it's the only way then that's fine. I'm just hoping there is something in LINQ that can help me achieve my goal.

Comment: How come `John` is having Child Id as 4 & 5? In DataTable it is 4 for both childrens? Same goes with other record.

Comment: @RahulSingh Typing error. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple `GroupBy` on ParentName, try this:-

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ParentName"))
                             .Select(x => new Parent
                                    {
                                        Name = x.Key,
                                        Child = x.Select(z => new Children
                                        {
                                            ChildID = z.Field<string>("ChildId"),
                                            Name = z.Field<string>("ChildName"),
                                            //If ChildBooks is `String`
                                            ChildBooks = String.Join(",",
                                               x.Select(b => b.Field<string>("Books")))
                                        }).ToList()
                                    });
```

Here is the Sample [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FWdvM9), it is not working in fiddler due to some error but you can copy paste and check in visual studio.

**Edit:**

In above query, if `ChildBooks` is of type `String` then you'll get comma separated books, But if you want `List<String>` as ChildBooks(then obviously they won't be comma separated) you can do this:-

```
ChildBooks = x.Select(b => b.Field<string>("Books")).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, I think this is what I need, but what if we added `public List<string> ChildBooks = new List<string>();` to the child class? How would you alter to fit this? See the modified question...

Comment: Please check my update, but please note, since you need a comma separated string in result, it will be a single string so you don't need a `List<string>` rather you need `string`.

Comment: Getting an error of `{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."}`

Comment: Your ChildId is `int` or `string`? You need to change the type passed to `Field` accordingly.

Comment: That's what's confusing. Everything in my custom classes is set to `string`.

Comment: In that case, I am sure the type in datatable is `int`, if you have not specifies it explicitly, you can do it while adding the column type like this :- `dt.Columns.Add("ChildId", typeof(string));` so that datatype in Datatable & custom type will be in sync and you won't get this error.

Comment: The data types in the table were `int`. Changed my classes, works perfect

Comment: One last thing, it looks like I get 2 records for `Suzy` instead of just 1 with a `List` of items. How can if fix this?

Comment: With your updated DataTable data, you need to group by both `ParentName` as well as `ChildId`, so your group by will look like:- `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Field<string>("ParentName"), x.Field<string>("ChildId"))`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the end answer that I needed. @RahulSingh led me to the correct path.

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Parent ID"))
     .Select(x => new Parent
     {
         ParentId = x.Key,
         Children = x.GroupBy(y => y.Field<int>("ChildID")).Select(z => new Children
         {
             ChildID = z.Key,
             Books = z.Select(b => b.Field<int>("Books")).ToList()
         }).ToList()
     });
```